# Write dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a problem to save the printed datum.
In below picture, all of data was calculated, and I tried to save the results to CSV file.
However, only the last line was saved.
In this case, what shall I do? 
Do I have to use the loop method?
Could give me some hints or solutions?

```
r = 2 
while r < 5:
   r = r+1
   tan = [] 
   for compo in theta:
       tan.append(math.tan(compo))

   disp =[]
   for i in df.loc[r]:
       disp.append(i)

   Vy = []
   for a in tan:
        for b in disp:
            if tan.index(a) == disp.index(b):
                Vy.append(float(a)*float(b))

   Final = []
   for neg in Vy:
       Final.append(abs(neg))

   df3 = pd.DataFrame([Final])
   print(df3)
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images, instead, paste the code into your question (now you can hit edit button) and highlight it again, and hit Ctrl+K

Comment: Your screenshot is truncated and I cannot see enough runnable code. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry about that I made a mistake, and I edited the post. Please give me some help.

Comment: So you want to write df3 into a csv?

Comment: Your indentation is messed up please fix. There is at least one outright error.

Comment: Yes, however, only last line was saved in the CSV, when I used the 'df3.to_csv('output.csv')'. I want to save all of the data in the CSV file. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Can you confirm that the output of Final is the whole data?

Comment: The output of 'print(df3) has three line's data. But, in 'output.csv', there is only one line data.

Comment: That is probably due to your console having line-wrapping but not your text editor.

Comment: In your code, unless you want to continue using the way this code handles duplicates (only the first's index matters), use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): `for a, b in zip(tan, disp): Vy.append(float(a)*float(b))` for a huge increase in efficiency and readability. If you were to do something else with the indices, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), again for efficiency & readability.

Answer (score 0):

How are there multiple lines? Perhaps this is due to your console having line-wrapping but not your text editor.